# BadKeyError: Invalid string key in Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

In my project (using Python, Html & Jinja2) I have a home_page with movie pictures that each picture leads to a specific page with the movie data. When I try to present the page with the movie data I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line  
1536, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 
1530, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 
1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 
1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572,  
in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, 
in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\imovie-good\main.py", line 67, in get
movie_data = db.get(self.request.get('movie_key'))
File "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1537, in get
return get_async(keys, **kwargs).get_result()
File "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1496, in 
get_async
keys, multiple = datastore.NormalizeAndTypeCheckKeys(keys)
File "C:\Program Files   
(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 178, in   
NormalizeAndTypeCheckKeys
keys = [_GetCompleteKeyOrError(key) for key in keys]
File "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 2739, in 
_GetCompleteKeyOrError
key = Key(arg)
File "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 378, in  
__init__
raise datastore_errors.BadKeyError('Invalid string key %s.' % encoded)
BadKeyError: Invalid string key .
```

This is my python code:

```
    import webapp2
    import jinja2
    import os
    import datetime
    import time
    import cgi
    from google.appengine.ext import db
    from google.appengine.api import users
    from google.appengine.api import images


    jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

    class Movie(db.Model):
        name = db.StringProperty()
        release_date = db.StringProperty()
        duration = db.StringProperty()
        director = db.StringProperty()
        actors = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        summary = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        picture = db.BlobProperty()
        trailer = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
        date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    class Movie_Data(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movie_key = self.request.get('movie_key')
            movie_data = Movie.get(movie_key)

    template_values = {'movie_data': movie_data}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('movie_data.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movie = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
            if movie.picture:
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
                self.response.out.write(movie.picture)
            else:
                self.response.out.write("No Image")

    class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            movies = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM Movie "
                                "ORDER BY release_date DESC LIMIT 5")
            template_values = { 'movies': movies}                                   
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('home_page.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    class Admin(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            template_values = {}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('admin.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


        def post(self):
            name = self.request.get('name')
            release_date = self.request.get('release_date')
            c = time.strptime(release_date,"%m/%d/%Y")
            release_date = time.strftime("%m%d%Y",c)
            duration = self.request.get('duration')
            director = self.request.get('director')
            actors = self.request.get('actors')
            summary = self.request.get('summary')
            picture = self.request.get('img')
            trailer = self.request.get('trailer')

            movie = Movie(key_name = name)
            movie.release_date = release_date
            movie.duration = duration
            movie.director = director
            movie.actors = actors
            movie.summary = summary
            movie.picture = db.Blob(picture)
            movie.trailer = trailer
            movie.put()
            self.redirect('/')



    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/admin', Admin), ('/', Main), ('/img', Image), ('/movie_data', Movie_Data)], debug=True)
```

This is my html for the home_page:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>Top Movies</th>

            {% for movie in movies %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{movie.key().name() }} &nbsp</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href = "/movie_data?movie_key = {{movie.key()}}"> <img src = "/img?img_id={{movie.key()}}"> </td>


            </tr>

            {% endfor %}

            <a href = "/admin">admin</a>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my movie_data html code:

```
  <html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan ="6">{{ movie_data.picture }}</td>
                    <td> Movie Name: {{movie_data.name}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Release Date: {{movie_data.release_date}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Duration (minutes): {{movie_data.duration}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Director: {{movie_data.director}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Actors: {{movie_data.actors}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> Summary: {{movie_data.summary}}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan ="2"> {{movie_data.trailer}} </td>
                </table>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use spaces in your urls:

```
/movie_data?movie_key={{movie.key()}}
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn we passed that error :) but now we get this error - do you know what we should do:                                              <td> <a href = "/add_comment?movie_key={{movie_data.key()}}">Add a comment </td>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: we fixed that also. Our main problem is trying to show a string - maybe it's because maybe our adding movie form is "multipart/form-data"? is there a problem with that and saving a string and then showing it?

Comment: Hrm, since all we did was remove spaces, that looks like a completely new and unrelated error.

Comment: yes you are right it's a different error. I hade the error when trying to show movie.trailer so i removed it. now it throws the error on movie.summary - the common thing between them is that they are saved as multiline strings and in the forms the input is 'textarea'. this is the error: File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\imovie-good\movie_data.html", line 22, in top-level template code
    <td> Summary: {{movie_data.summary}}</td>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)